# Python and ffmpeg RTSP

Tags: python

I need to send a real time video from a Raspberry to a Jetson NX using python

When I launch this code:

```
import subprocess
import socket

HOST = '192.168.43.42'  # Host IP address
PORT = 5001  # Port number
WIDTH = 640  # Width of the video frame
HEIGHT = 480  # Height of the video frame
BITRATE = 1000000  # Bitrate of the video stream

server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_socket.bind((HOST, PORT))
server_socket.listen(1)
print('Server listening on port', PORT)

# Start ffmpeg subprocess and pipe output to socket
ffmpeg_cmd = ['ffmpeg', '-f', 'v4l2', '-framerate', '30', '-video_size', '640x480', '-input_format', 'mjpeg', '-i',
              '/dev/video0', '-preset', 'faster', '-']

ffmpeg_proc = subprocess.Popen(ffmpeg_cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
connection, client_address = server_socket.accept()
print('Client connected:', client_address)

try:
    while True:
        # Read video data from ffmpeg stdout and send it to client
        data = ffmpeg_proc.stdout.read(1024)
        if not data:
            break
        connection.sendall(data)
finally:
    ffmpeg_proc.kill()
    connection.close()
    server_socket.close()
```

I get the following error:

```
[NULL @ 0x560ef01ab5c0] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'pipe:'
pipe:: Invalid argument
```

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. Because `-` doesn't have a file extension, it doesn't imply an output format, so you need to specify one explicitly.

Comment: (put `-f rtsp` after the input-related specs, _before_ the `-` specifying where the output should go).